# How to adjust spacing and number formatting in a youtube-dl output template?

Tags: youtube-dl

I am using `youtube-dl`. The command that I use is:

```bash
youtube-dl LinkOfVideo -o S0%(season_number)s-0%(episode_number)s-%(episode)s.%(ext)s
```

The output filename of the above command is:

```bash
S01-02-Title-ID.mp4
```

First, I want a single space between every hyphen. Like this:

```bash
S01 - E02 - Title - ID.mp4
```

Another problem is with `0`. Think what will be After `E09`. What will be the next number? It will be `E010`. So the full name will be like this:

```bash
S012 - E036 - Title - ID.mp4
```

I don't like that. I want names after tens, like:

```bash
S12 - E32 - Title - ID.mp4
```

Comment: Use the that command like this `-o S%(season_number)s  -  %(episode_number)s  - 
 %(episode)s.%(ext)s` adding your spaces and removing the `0`s

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen downloaded video file name is S1.mp4  Not working

Comment: Sorry missed the `''`, use `-o 'S%(season_number)s - %(episode_number)s - %(episode)s.%(ext)s'`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Would you be willing to post that, or something like it, as an answer?

Comment: @Varun You had originally tagged this [tag:windows-10]. Is that because this is a WSL system (where you're running Ubuntu in Windows 10) or for some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

If one wanted the two digit Season and Episode numbers this would properly be accomplished using the python style string formatting youtube-dl offers:

```
youtube-dl -o "S%(season_number)02d - E%(episode_number)02d - %(episode)s - %(id)s.%(ext)s" LinkOfVideo
```

Use the '02d' flags instead of the 's' conversion type (string). The 'd' signifies that it is an integer decimal type, the '0' that it should be padded with 0's, and the '2' that it should be 2 digits in length.

Answer (score 0):

Your command:

```
youtube-dl LinkOfVideo -o S0%(season_number)s-0%(episode_number)s-%(episode)s.%(ext)s
```

can be changed to:

```
youtube-dl LinkOfVideo -o 'S%(season_number)s - %(episode_number)s - %(episode)s - ID.%(ext)s'
```

Note that the format is `%(variable_name)s` and any other additions to that will be yours to make. So remove the `0` and add the spaces you need to get that output.